# How to select radio buttons using fdfgen and pdftk?

Tags: pdftk, fdf, fdfgen

How to select radio buttons using fdfgen and pdftk?

https://github.com/ccnmtl/fdfgen

I have tried using the values True, 'true', 1, 'On', 'on', 'Yes', 'Selected'

Comment: Could not figure it out. Replaced it with check-boxes.

Answer (score -1):

If you have acces to Adobe Acrobat Pro, open your PDF and clic on Forms > Edit (In the menu on the left).

Left clic on your radio button, Properties > Options. The "Export Value" is the value you must give your field when populating your form.

Comment: no access to acrobat pro. doing it with libreoffice, fdfgen and pdftk programatically

Comment: this didnt worked for me.  I use the Export Value within the pdftk command to fill out a form and it doesn't pick any of the radio buttons in the form.  What elses can be done for this??